# Calculating a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $$\int_{D}(x-2y)^2\sin(x+2y)\,dx\,dy$$ where $D$ is a triangle with vertices in $(0,0), (2\pi,0),(0,\pi)$.

I've tried using the substitution $g(u,v)=(2\pi u, \pi v)$ to make it a BIT simpler but honestly, it doesn't help much.

What are the patterns I need to look for in these problems so I can get an integral that's viable to calculate? Everything I try always leads to integrating a huge function and that's extremely error prone.

I mean, I can obviously see the $x-2y$ and $x+2y$ but I don't know how to use it to my advantage. Also, when I do my substitution, I get $\sin(2\pi(u+v))$ and in the triangle I have, $u+v$ goes from 0 to 1, so the $\sin$ goes full circle. Again, no idea if that helps me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use the substitution $u = x-2y$ and $v = x+2y$.

Comment: How would I calculate the boundaries of the new integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to have been designed for the use of  variable substitutions and  a Jacobian determinant. **Luka Horvat**'s intuition is proper, and  **Santiago Canez** makes the proposal, that  substitutions  $ \ u \ = \ x - 2y \ , \ v \ = \ x + 2y \ $ , will be helpful.  The triangular region of integration is transformed into one symmetrical about the $ \ y-$ axis, as seen below.

[image]

In order to complete the expression of the transformed integral, we need to calculate the Jacobian determinant $ \ \mathfrak{J} \ $ of the transformation.  We can either find the determinant of the *inverse* transformation,

$$ \mathfrak{J}^{-1} \ = \  \left|  \ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{array} \  \right| \ = \  \left|  \ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{array} \  \right| \ = \ 4 \ \ , $$

and use  $ \ \mathfrak{J} \ = \ \frac{1}{\mathfrak{J}^{-1}} \ = \ \frac{1}{4} \ $ , **or** solve for $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ in terms of $ \ u \ $ and $ \ v \ $ [not difficult for *these* variables] to obtain  $ \ x \ = \ \frac{u+v}{2} \ , $ $ y \ = \ \frac{v-u}{4} \ $ and the determinant for the transformation,

$$ \mathfrak{J} \ = \  \left|  \ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{array} \  \right| \ = \  \left|  \ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \end{array} \  \right| \ = \ \frac{1}{4} \ \ . $$

The integral carried over the transformed triangle can be split (at least for the moment) into  left- and right-hand halves as

$$ \int_{-2 \pi}^0 \int_{-u}^{2 \pi} \ \mathfrak{J} \cdot (u^2 \sin v) \ \ dv \ du \ \ + \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0 \int_{u}^{2 \pi} \ \mathfrak{J} \cdot (u^2 \sin v) \ \ dv \ du   $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{4} \ \left[ \ \int_{-2 \pi}^0  \   (-u^2 \cos v) \vert_{-u}^{2 \pi}   \ \  du \ \ + \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \ (-u^2 \cos v) \vert_{u}^{2 \pi} \ \  du  \ \right]  $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{4} \ \left[ \ \int_{-2 \pi}^0  \   \left(  -u^2 \ [\cos (2 \pi) \ - \ \cos(-u) ] \ \right)   \ \  du \ \ + \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \ \left(  -u^2 \ [\cos (2 \pi) \ - \ \cos(u) ] \ \right) \ \  du  \ \right]  $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{4} \ \left[ \ \int_{-2 \pi}^0  \   \left(  -u^2 \ [1 \ - \ \cos(u) ] \ \right)   \ \  du \ \ + \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \ \left(  -u^2 \ [1 \ - \ \cos(u) ] \ \right) \ \  du  \ \right]  $$

[the terms of the integrands are even functions, so we can merge the integrals and exploit the symmetry]

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{4} \  \int_{-2 \pi}^{2 \pi}  \   u^2 \cos u   \ - \ u^2 \     \  du   \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{4}  \cdot 2 \   \int_0^{2 \pi}  \   u^2 \cos u   \ - \ u^2 \     \  du  $$

[integrating the first term of the integrand by parts twice]

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \left( \ [ \ (u^2 - 2) \sin u \ + \ 2u \cos u   \ ] \ - \ \frac{1}{3}u^3 \ \right) \vert_0^{2 \pi}    $$

$$ = \  \frac{1}{2} \ \left[ \   2 \cdot 2 \pi \cdot  \cos (2 \pi)   \ - \ \frac{1}{3}  (2 \pi)^3 \ \right] \vert_0^{2 \pi} \ \ = \ \ 2 \pi    \ - \ \frac{4 \pi^3}{3}  \ \ .  $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I calculate those types of integral on plane.
$$\int_D 1\,dy dx = \mathrm{Area \;of \; triangle}$$

Now, area of triangle is just area under the straight line.
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left ( \pi - \frac x2\right ) dx$$
Now I change single integral into double integral,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{ \pi - \frac x2 } \,dy\right)\, dx$$
Finally I substitute that thing inside it and evaluate it.
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{ \pi - \frac x2 } (x-2y)^2\sin(x+2y)dydx$$

Somehow [wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B+%28x%E2%88%922y%29%5E2sin%28x%2B2y%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+2pi%7D%2C+%7By%2C+0%2C+pi-x%2F2%7D%5D) calculates it to be $2 \pi -\frac{4 \pi ^3}{3}$.

Comment: Well, I got to that part, not evaluating the actual integral is proving very difficult. There's usually an approach I can take that will make the integral much easier.

Comment: @LukaHorvat Huh?? do you mean that you have problem evaluating that integral?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. I meant "now" instead of "not".

Comment: @LukaHorvat Use Integration by Parts, ... twice for inner integral.

Comment: As I said, this is the part I need help with. We get way to many of these problems on a single test to be able to "brute force" each integral. There IS an approach where the integral you actually have to evaluate is relatively simple. Integration by parts, TWICE is way too long.

Comment: @LukaHorvat sorry, I had made error on inputing on wolf. From the looks of output, I don't think there is any symmetry involved. And there is no escape from $\int x^2 \sin(x) dx $. lol ... I myself don't feel like evaluating that integral :(

Answer (score 0):

Your integral can be evaluated as an iterated integral and bunch of integration-by-parts:
$$
   \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi-2y}(x-2y)^{2}\sin(x+2y)dxdy \\
   = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{2y}^{2\pi}(x-4y)^{2}\sin(x)\,dx dy \\
   = \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\left.-(x-4y)^{2}\cos(x)\right|_{x=2y}^{x=2\pi}+\int_{2y}^{2\pi}2(x-4y)\cos(x)\,dx\right)\,dy \\
   = \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(-(2\pi-4y)^{2}+4y^{2}\cos(2y)+\int_{2y}^{2\pi}2(x-4y)\cos(x)\,dx\right)\,dy \\
   = \int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\left.-(2\pi-4y)^{2}+4y^{2}\cos(2y)+2(x-4y)\sin(x)\right|_{x=2y}^{2\pi}-\int_{2y}^{2\pi}2\sin(x)\,dx\right)\,dy \\
   =\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(-(2\pi-4y)^{2}+4y^{2}\cos(2y)+4y\sin(2y)+(2-2\cos(2y))\right)\,dy \\
   = \left.\left[\frac{1}{12}(2\pi -4y)^{3}+2y^{2}\sin(2y)+(2y-\sin(2y))\right] \right|_{y=0}^{\pi} \\
   = -\frac{4\pi^{3}}{3}+2\pi.
$$
I get the same answer as wolf.